# Issue in programming IPv6 route in linux kernel with IPv4 mapped IPv6 address as next hop addess

Tags: linux, networking, ip, routing, ipv6

Kernel Version: 4.0.5

Commands executed on Linux terminal:

1. ip tuntap add mode tap dummy_1
2. ip -6 addr add ::FFFF:A9FE:0005/120 dev dummy_1
3. ip -6 neigh add ::FFFF:A9FE:000A lladdr 00:a9:fe:00:05:ff dev dummy_1
4. ip -6 route add 1111::1111/128 via ::FFFF:A9FE:000A dev dummy_1

Output: Invalid argument for command no 4

The same set of commands are working on Linux kernel 4.16.

But kernel version 4.0.5 or below that, IPv4 mapped IPv6 address showing invalid and same behavior was also observed when I was trying to ping the local address on dummy_1 with

ping6 ::FFFF:A9FE:0005

Connect: Dest unreachable

Comment: Hmm, since 4.0.x series is old and unsupported (not even as LTS) and the issue no longer exists in 4.16, is there any point in investigating it any further? Just call it "a bug that was fixed in a later release".

Comment: But that said... why does your command #4 use `1111::1111/64` as the destination network? I kind of suspect that it's rejected because it's supposed to be a network address but has host bits set; have you tried `1111::/64` or `1111::1111/128` instead?

Comment: sorry, I tried with 1111::1111/128. The same issue persists. Actually I have to give support in that particular kernel(4.0.5). I was wondering if there is any other way to tackle this issue? Moreover I am not sure if IPv4 mapped IPv6 address routes are supported or not in those kernels. Do you have any clue about the kernel version from where they have started giving this support?

Comment: But is there a specific reason to even use mapped addresses in this situation? They seem to be a completely meaningless translation – any standard address (e.g. a fe80::* address) will do the job, especially if you statically configure the neighbour entry anyway.

Comment: I would not expect this to work at all, and would not attempt it.

Comment: The problem is , I need to assign an IPv6 address to a dummy tap interface(for special use) . So I was trying to use a special IPv6 address which can't be configured/used by operator. So I choose IPv4 mapped IPv6 address. Any light on this issue.?